# ¿Cómo hago para que Tornado me cargue el JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, api

Hoy estuve probando hacer una API en Python, con el framework **Tornado**. Pero me encontré con un error que me está costando resolver un poco, y además, no veo muchas soluciones en internet. **Cuando ejecuto este código...**

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web 
import json

class Index(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        archivo = "prueba.json"
        apertura = open(archivo, "r")
        data = json.load(apertura)
        self.write(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = tornado.web.Application([
        (r'/',Index)
    ])
    app.listen(8888)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

**me tira este error:**

```
TypeError: write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects. Lists not accepted for security reasons; see http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/web.html#tornado.web.RequestHandler.write
```

**¿Qué puede estar fallando acá?**

Comment: El error está diciendo que no acepta directamente el json, podrías intentar con `self.write(json.dumps(data))` para escribir la representación textual del json que has cargado. Aunque si estás seguro de la validez del archivo no veo la necesidad de convertirlo a json y luego de nuevo a cadena, se podría hacer más directo (y más eficiente). Por favor confirmame si funciona y es lo que buscas para escribir una respuesta.

Comment: @jachguate si, funcionó! Muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En lugar de escribir:

```
self.write(data)
```

tenía que escribir

```
self.write(json.dumps(data))
```

para que pueda convertir el archivo nuevamente a formato JSON, ya que, como estaba escrito en el primer código, no aceptaba el JSON así como lo estaba cargando yo. Necesitaba reconvertir el archivo con el `json.dumps(data)`, adentro del `self.write()`